# Is there an equivalent in SQL as microtime() for PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I assumed there would be a query you can make in SQL for this, microtime() is derived from the server environment so I hoped there would be a 'like-for-like' in SQL, but I can't see it. Im using MSSQL but would be interested in other dbs too.

Comment: What database engine are you using (MySQL? PostrgeSQL> SQLite?) This kind of thing is not really a part of standard SQL, so different systems will have different functions available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming MySQL, can you try something like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5913) which also shows the use of MySQLs MicroSecond method.

--EDIT

Since you're using SQL Server, can this work:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7679).

Comment: It's a MSSQL database sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
    select cast(datediff(second,'19700101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as varchar)
+'.'+ cast(DATEPART(microsecond,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of MYSQL 5.6.4 to emulate `microtime()` you can use

```
select concat(mod(unix_timestamp(now(6)),1),'00 ',unix_timestamp());
```

and to emulate `microtime(true)`

```
select concat(unix_timestamp(now(6)),'00');
```

The '`00`' on both queries is there because MYSQL has a precision of only 6 digits. More info on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now